# Postgres Vulnerability through public schema?

Tags: debian, postgresql, tmp, vulnerability

On Debian 8.5, I'm finding weird processes and files in `/tmp`:

```
file "cool" is owned by root, group=postgres<br>
file "Injection.sh", "zeroteam.so", "zteam"
```

Why do those file exist? How can I figure out what they are doing?

**UPDATE/EDIT**:

I found something. So it looks like it is malware, which was downloaded by the postgres user, I can see the entries in the postgresql-log where it downloads the various files from an unknown ip.

How were they able to do this? I guess it has something to do with the default public schema. Is this correct?

I restarted the database with an updated config to prevent all access to the database from outside. Not sure if that's enough or whether I'll have to do a clean rebuild of the system.

Any additional information is appreciated.

Comment: You should backup all your data and reinstall the whole system.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What are the risks? There was only a breach of a user (postgres) without root access. Of course the safest way is to reinstall, but I'd like to learn why.

Comment: `file "cool" is owned by root` is a serious sign that your system is/was owned. Here is a full answer : http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server